# Javascript addEventListener: Getting variable to persist with it

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, addeventlistener

I'm currently learning Javascript, and now I'm messing around with eventlisteners.

But I have a problem, when I make the eventlisteners in a loop, I can't figure out how to pass it a variable that persists with it.
I have made a script that moves a element to a specified position when I click it. But now it puts all the elements in the same position, so for some reason they are all getting the same numbers.

No matter if I pass it in as this:

```
var index = i;    

applications[i].addEventListener('click', function(){ 

 
var posLeft2 = 10*index+"%";

 var iconstyleO =  " text-align: center; "+
" font: bold 22px Tahoma; "+
" position:fixed; "+
" top: 67%; "+
" left: "+posLeft2+"; "+
" display:block; "+
" margin: 150px auto; "+
" color: #ffffff; "+
" z-index: 3; "+
" -webkit-border-radius: 10px; "+
" background: rgb(140,140,140); "+
" width: 10%; "+
" height: 10%; ";

this.setAttribute('style',iconstyleO); 
     }  ,false);
```

or like this:

```
var index = i;    

applications[i].addEventListener('click', function(index){ 

 
var posLeft2 = 10*index+"%";

 var iconstyleO =  " text-align: center; "+
" font: bold 22px Tahoma; "+
" position:fixed; "+
" top: 67%; "+
" left: "+posLeft2+"; "+
" display:block; "+
" margin: 150px auto; "+
" color: #ffffff; "+
" z-index: 3; "+
" -webkit-border-radius: 10px; "+
" background: rgb(140,140,140); "+
" width: 10%; "+
" height: 10%; ";

this.setAttribute('style',iconstyleO); 
     }  ,false);
```

They are still setting the eventlisteners to the same position. Either at the last elements position, or at the first elements position, depending on how I try to pass it in.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript does not have block scope.
Therefore, all of your callbacks are sharing the same variable.

To fix this, you need to wrap your code in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), so that each callback gets its own closure:

```
(function(index) {
    applications[i].addEventListener('click', function(){ 
        ...
    });
})(i);
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm! Happy newyears eve!